Is there any way to detect Double Tap and Long Press event in framer-motion?
I'm using framer-motion in my React project and I need to detect both Double Tap and Long Press events on a particular element.
Framer Motion provides built-in handlers like onTap and onTapStart, but I'm not sure how to extend these to differentiate between single taps, double taps, and long presses.
